# How can Scala understand function calls in different formats?

Tags: parsing, scala, programming-languages, compilation

I realize the following function calls are all same, but I do not understand why.

```
val list = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))

list.map(_.length)   // res0 = List(1,2,3) result of 1st call

list map(_.length)   // res1 = List(1,2,3) result of 2nd call

list map (_.length)  // res2 = List(1,2,3) result of 3rd call
```

I can understand 1st call, which is just a regular function call because map is a member function of class List

But I can not understand 2nd and 3rd call. For example, in the 3rd call, how can Scala compiler know "(_.length)" is parameter of "map"? How can compiler know "map" is a member function of "list"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between variant 2 and 3 is the blank in front of the parenthesis? This can only be a delimiter - `list a` and `lista` is of course different, but a opening parens is a new token, and you can put a blank or two or three in front - or none. I don't see how you can expect a difference here.

In Java, there is no difference between

```
 System.out.println ("foo");
```

// and

```
 System.out.println("foo");
```

too.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: Oh, yes, thanks. That was a misleading comment of mine; removed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the operator notation. The reason it works is the same reason why `2 + 2` works.

The space is used to distinguish between words -- `listmap(_.length)` would make the compiler look for `listmap`. But if you write `list++list`, it will work too, as will `list ++ list`.

So, one you are using operator notation, the space is necessary to separate words, but otherwise may be present or not.